# Echo tag (text) not visible on page

Tags: php, css

I added a simple PHP echo tag on my website:

```
<?php echo "Test"; ?>
```

This message should be displayed above the header (which has a green background. The header moves a little, but I can't see the text "Test".
Then I tried this code:

```
<?php echo "<h1>Test</h1>"; ?>
```

Again, the header moves a little more, but the text is invisible.

First:
[image: First]

After the normal echo tag:
[image: Second]

After adding h1:
[image: Third]

Can you help me?

Comment: Why not inspect the header to see if their is any content in there besides the "Home/Blog" text?

Comment: Is your text color the same as the background?

Comment: This is likely a CSS issue not a PHP issue, so it's difficult to know without seeing your CSS and HTML. Setting up a Codepen would help people figure out the issue.

Comment: Hi I made a codepen (unfortunately without pictures) I made the php a comment, because it would look weird. https://codepen.io/underlyingglitch/pen/GGNLgb

Comment: So the text "Test" is echoed even before <!DOCTYPE html>? That can't be right.

Comment: What do you get when you press Ctrl + A? I'm pretty sure that you can see the Test after that. Because the markup/css is just not added properly

Comment: Knowing the context would help.

Comment: For the record: I can not see "test" with the developer mode in my brower.... Then I see this: (::before) before my "HOME / BLOG"

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP `echo` needs to be inside the HTML `body` element to be displayed on the page. Everything else you see is a result of the browser attempting to correct invalid HTML (which can look very different between different browsers).

Comment: This is the correct answer. OP, please make sure that all of your expected output is inside the `<body>` tag. Can you use `Developer Tools` from your browser to see where your tag is being put now?